# Exception while making SSL connection from within Windows Service

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-services

I'm developing simple Windows Service sending and receiving data from remote web service.
I decided to use WebClient class for it's simplicity and enhanced it to include certificate in request, like this:

```
class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    public X509Certificate cert { set; get; }
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        req.ClientCertificates.Clear();
        req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
        return req;
    }
}
```

This is how i prepare and make requests:

```
try {
//...
string qry = "Some xml query...";
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object sender,
    X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain,
    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(appPath + @"\data\cert.der");
MyWebClient cl = new MyWebClient();
cl.cert = cert;
string xmlReq = qry; 
cl.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/xml";
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlReq);
byte[] res = cl.UploadData(apiUrl, data);
cl.Dispose();

string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(res);
} catch (Exception ex) {
//...
}
//...
```

Now, i know that loading certificate from file is not the best idea, but that's not the point. The point is that above code works perfectly in desktop application, but throws "Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS" exception in Windows Service.
I tried to install the service under "localService" and "networkService" account and it makes no diffirence.

UPDATE: installing under "user" didn't help also.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there any more detail in the exception (eg. `InnerException`)? Can use connect to the endpoint with a browser? If yes, what does it show about the server certificate?

Comment: @Richard: the inner exception is null. The service is based on a windows desktop application that works perfectly well, that's why i'm scratching my head for two days now...

Comment: Have you tried installing the service as the user that can run the desktop application properly?

Comment: The service doesn't run the desktop application. What i meant is that the code is based on desktop application code.

Comment: DeadYCool I think where @CoreTech is going is trying to get you to eliminate the user as the source of the problem.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan Well, i have just tried that and it didn't help.

Comment: Okay well that helps eliminate that as an issue then.

Comment: Is the server certificate or its issuing CA certificate (if not one of the pre-installed CA certificates) install in the machine's certificate store (as opposed to the user's)?

Comment: @Bruno, this certificate is not installed. I load it directly from .der file.

Comment: @DeadYCool, I'm not talking about the client certificate, I'm talking about the server certificate. Was it issued by a well known CA supported by your browser by default, or is it self-signed or issued by an internal CA (in which case you must have imported it or its CA cert explicitly at some point).

Comment: @Bruno: i explicitly accept any server certificate. I updated my snippet to show that.

Comment: Ah OK (bad practice, though, but OK for testing in some cases). The other thing that comes to mind is that the client cert shouldn't work at all: there's no private key in your DER file, and you'd obviously need it for client-certificate authentication. Perhaps it's picked up automatically from your local user store when you run it as a normal user, which may explain the different behaviour.

Comment: @Bruno: unfortunately that's not the case, because i do not have this certificate installed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6581/discussion-between-bruno-and-deadycool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load a certificate with this:

```
X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(appPath + @"\data\cert.der");
```

You're only loading the certificate. However, for client-certificate authentication to work, you **need** to provide the private key too (otherwise, anyone could use any certificate).

Following the discussion in the chat room, you've indicated you also have a `.p12` (PKCS#12), a `.key` and `.pem` file, as will as the `.der` file you were trying to load.
Usually, these extensions are used in this way:

- `.der` for the certificate itself in DER encoding (binary).
- `.pem` for the certificate itself in PEM encoding (base64-encoding of DER, within `---BEGIN....--- ... --- END ---` delimiters).
- `.key` for the private key.
- `.p12` (or `.pfx`) for the PKCS#12 file, which will contain both the certificate (and possibly the CA chain) and the private key.

In .Net, the base `X509Certificate` will not allow you to load a private key along with the certificate. You should look into loading the p12 file into a [`X509Certificate2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx) instance: it's essentially a convenience class that not only models certificates, but can associate a private key to the object too.

I'm not sure why this worked as a desktop application and not as a service. My guess is that it would have picked up a cert+private key from the user or machine store automatically in one of the situations. Either way, your desktop application was not authenticating simply with the DER file anyway.

Comment: For creating an `X509Certificate2` instance from a PKCS#12 (p12/pfx) file, this should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148420.aspx